# translating bytes from korean to utf-8, what am I not getting here?

Tags: java, utf-8, character-encoding, internationalization

There is obviously something incomplete about my understanding here. If I run the code below, I expect to see:

```
 translateTest:: start
  start_korean: (6)  c0 af c8 f1 c8 c6
 expected_utf8: (6)  c7 20 d7 6c d6 c8
    found_utf8: (6)  c7 20 d7 6c d6 c8
 expected utf8 matches found? true
```

What I get is:

```
 translateTest:: start
  start_korean: (6)  c0 af c8 f1 c8 c6
 expected_utf8: (6)  c7 20 d7 6c d6 c8
    found_utf8: (9)  ec 9c a0 ed 9d ac ed 9b 88
 expected utf8 matches found? false
```

I think that creating the string, declaring the bytes to be x-windows-949, and then getting the bytes as utf-8 will translate them from one to the other. Apparently, I am not correct about this.

```
public class translateTest {

  public static void main (String [] Argv) {
      (new translateTest()).translate();
  }

  void translate() {
    System.out.println("translateTest:: start");

    try {

      // pages below linked from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/goglobal/cc305154

      // Please ignore the lame bytesToHex helper method. Including it for completeness.

      // from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/goglobal/gg696909
      //
      // 0xC0AF =  U+C720 = HANGUL SYLLABLE IEUNG YU

      // from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/goglobal/gg696960
      //
      // 0xC8F1 =  U+D76C = HANGUL SYLLABLE HIEUH YI

      // also from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/goglobal/gg696960
      //
      // 0xC8C6 =  U+D6C8 = HANGUL SYLLABLE HIEUH U NIEUN

      byte[] start_korean = new byte[] { (byte)0xC0, (byte)0xAF, (byte)0xC8, (byte)0xF1, (byte)0xC8, (byte)0xC6 };
      byte[] expected_utf8 = new byte[] { (byte)0xC7, (byte)0x20, (byte)0xD7, (byte)0x6C, (byte)0xD6, (byte)0xC8 };
      String str = new String(start_korean, "x-windows-949");
      byte[] found_utf8 = str.getBytes("utf8");

      boolean isEqual = java.util.Arrays.equals(expected_utf8, found_utf8);

      System.out.println(" start_korean: "+bytesToHex(start_korean));
      System.out.println("expected_utf8: "+bytesToHex(expected_utf8));
      System.out.println("   found_utf8: "+bytesToHex(found_utf8));

      System.out.println("expected utf8 matches found? "+isEqual);

    } catch (java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
      System.err.println(uee.getMessage());
    }
  }

  public static String bytesToHex(byte[] b) {
    StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer("("+b.length+") ");
    for (int idx = 0; idx < b.length; idx++) {
      str.append(" "+byteToHex(b[idx]));
    }
    return str.toString();
  }

  public static String byteToHex(byte b) {
    String hex = Integer.toHexString(b);
    while (hex.length() < 2) hex = "0"+hex;
    if (hex.length() > 2)
      hex = hex.substring(hex.length()-2);
    return hex;
  }
}
```

Comment: btw,% java -version
java version "1.6.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_51-b11-457-10M4509)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.51-b01-457, mixed mode)

Comment: +1 for a good question with a _compilable_ and _runnable_ SSCCE.  In fact, this is a model of SO question goodness :-)

Comment: This makes no sense. *Korean* is not an encoding.

Comment: I am ok with that. Did you look at the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that your "expected UTF8" values are actually the Unicode code points and NOT the UTF-8 encoding of those code points.  I added this to your code:

```
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i++) buf.append(", ").append(Integer.toHexString(str.codePointAt(i)));
    System.out.println("     internal: "+buf.substring(2));
```

producing the values you show.

When these code points get UTF-8 encoded, they are rendered into the values you actually see.

Use the online [Unicode Code Converter](http://rishida.net/tools/conversion/) to check this out.  Enter the string `c720 d76c d6c8` in the "mixed input" box and click "Convert numbers as hex code points".

Comment: If I use (new String(start_korean, "MS949")), then I get exactly the same result.

Comment: by the way, "MS949" and "x-windows-949" both give the same answer.

Comment: Yeah, I guess either one can be used... the docs seem to say otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

@JimGarrison is right: if you try to convert the original string to UTF-16 big endian,
you'll see "expected utf-8"-

```
    System.out.println("          try: " + bytesToHex(str.getBytes("UTF-16BE")));
```

This means, that the string is:

```
"\uc720\ud76c\ud6c8"
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. We've got users with one of about 80 different language settings and we are trying to see how we will know they are all working.... This will help.